# Update the data using a field in MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Here I want to update the password field in my MongoDB database. I have to search the particular document based on a field called email. Where the email matches with that particular document password field should be updated. this is my code.

```
resetPassword(passwordData) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/api/forgotpassword/'+passwordData.emailId,passwordData,{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

This code is from routes `user.js`

```
router.put('/forgotpassword/', function(req,res) {

});
```

How should I do This operation? Can someone help me with the coding?

Comment: what was the problem you were facing?

Comment: I don't know how to write the code for the problem I've mentioned. code for `user.js` file.